# How to solve error created while sending JSON data using wget from unix server to a dashboard

Tags: bash, unix, curl, http-post, wget

I want to send some message in json format from unix server to a Dashboard. And I have a shell script like below.

```
#!/bin/sh
message="Hello, Aurora"
scriptname="hello_script_1_controlmQA"

generate_post_data()
{
 cat <<EOF
{
    "data":"{\"actiontodo\":\"Action to do for test nr:
    1\",\"critical\":\"LOW\",\"fixstatus\":\"NOTCONCERN\",\"host\":\"MTR_SOME_HOST\",\"message\":\"$message\" 
,\"mgsApplication\":\"MTR\",\"sMxtype\":\"PROD\",\"scriptname\":\"$scriptname\"}",
    "msg":"NotificationReceiveDTO without dict to send at: 2020-06-07T11:14:09.794 Created at: 2020- 
 06-07T11:14:09.797",
    "msgType":"DATA"
 }
EOF
}


/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate --header="Accept: application/json" -- 
header="Content-Type:application/json" --post-data "$(generate_post_data)" 
"https://cas.internal.unicreditgroup.eu:8181/Aurora/rs/nores/renosub"
```

When I execute this script it is logging an error message in renosub file as:
{"msg":"Wrong parse WebSocMessage: Unexpected char 10 at (line no=2, column no=213, offset=214)","msgType":0}

This message I have received from the Dashboard where I want to post this JSON message. How do I solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. In this case, please add what you have tried to solve this problem and what error you encounter.

Comment: Hi @toydarian, I have changed the content and highlighted the issue which needs to be resolved as advised. I need help in this regards. :)

Comment: Your json is incorrect according to [https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). It seems you're trying to send a json string in a json string `"data":"{\"a...` and you're missing a `}`.

Comment: Hi @Bayou, Could you please help correct the json string. I am new to json subject area.

Comment: @Sneha please accept answers if it answers your question. (Also for your other questions).

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to send as follows, but I'm not sure because I don't know your systems. Try indenting the data next time, it will be easier to debug.

```
{
   "data":{
      "actiontodo":"Action to do for test nr:  1",
      "critical":"LOW",
      "fixstatus":"NOTCONCERN",
      "host":"MTR_SOME_HOST",
      "message":"$message",
      "mgsApplication":"MTR",
      "sMxtype":"PROD",
      "scriptname":"$scriptname"
   },
   "msg":"NotificationReceiveDTO without dict to send at: 2020-06-07T11:14:09.794 Created at: 2020-06-07T11:14:09.797",
   "msgType":"DATA"
}
```

You can enclose this with:

```sh
generate_post_data() {
    cat <<-EOF
        # Literal json data here. 
    EOF
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi @Bayou,thank you for the above suggestion. I will try applying this solution and then mark this as answered.

Comment: Hi @bayou I am getting this kind of error now when I run the script:                         
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2020-08-21 12:22:19 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.                                                    Is this error in my script or the webpage where I am trying to post? How to resolve this

Comment: HTTP errors in the range 500 are always server errors AFAIK. It can be that your json is missing something, but I can't review that for you.